# Java return outside of a for each loop

Tags: java, object, return, return-type

Simple dummy question ... I'v created a method who send me a object after a for loop. The for loop make a return of my object in question. But Java ask me to send a return in the bottom of the method. The problem is... I don't have anything to return outside of my method. There is a ways to tell im to only return a error?

Here the code in question ... pretty simple!

```
public Stock getStockInfos(String selectedStock) {
    for(Stock temp:registreStock){
        if((temp.getSymbol()).equals(selectedStock)){
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, I need to add a return statement at the end ... One solution I'v find, is to make a copy of temp and return this copy at the bottom. If this is the right solution, there is a easy way to copy/clone this object?

Comment: your method signature promises to return a Stock.  the for loop and the condition doesn't guarantee a match.  What should happen if there is no match?  One way to address this is to return a null and delegate the handling to the caller.

Comment: As you method declares a return type you need to return something if you if statement results in always false. You could return an optional empty at the end of the method if nothing found. Or just null. But optional would be safer.

Comment: If none of the stock matches the selected stock symbol, what should your method return?

Comment: "return a error" usually means "throw an exception"

Comment: Declare temp outside (before) the for-loop. Search for "java variable scope".

Comment: If you're thinking "I don't know what to return if the symbol doesn't exist, I don't think that can even happen" then the best practice is to fail fast by throwing an exception. You should only `return null;` if you want to return null, and not as an "I don't know".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ask yourself if it could happen that you don't find a stock for the given symbol and what should happen in such a case. One option would be to return null or to raise an exception.

```
public Stock getStockInfos(String selectedStock) {
    for(Stock temp:registreStock){
        if((temp.getSymbol()).equals(selectedStock)){
            return temp;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need a return value for all execution paths.

```
   public Stock getStockInfos(String selectedStock) {
   
     for(Stock temp:registreStock){
          if((temp.getSymbol()).equals(selectedStock)){
            return temp;
          }
      }

    // This line of code will not be reached assuming return temp is executed - 
    // but will take care of the message
   return null ;
   }
```

And of course the code that calls this method must test for null that may be returned.

Comment: Yep! that's working! Don't understand why I was not eable to do it earlyer... certainly a newbie error! :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'v done that and it's working

```
    public Stock getStockInfos(String selectedStock) {
    Stock stockSelected = null;
    for(Stock temp:registreStock){
        if((temp.getSymbol()).equals(selectedStock)){
            stockSelected = temp;
        }
    }
    return stockSelected;
}
```

But... yeah... I need to tink if the object are not found! you are right!

Thanks I will think again!!! :P

Comment: you should add a `break;` after finding the match.

Answer (score 0):

If `registreStock` is collection, you can use stream and `Optional` instead of nullable values. Like this:

```
Optional<Stock> result = registreStock
    .stream()
    .filter((stock) -> stock.getSymbol().equals(selectedStock))
    .findFirst();
```

Returning `null` is bad practice. Use `Optional` if possible.